# JS - preventing several audio files from playing at the same time

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, addeventlistener

I wrote a function that iterates over an array, creates a `querySelector`, an `audio` element, and `addsEventListener` to play the audio element when clicking on a button.

The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to play just one track at a time. The ideal behavior would be that when the user clicks on a button, all of the other tracks stop or pause.

I tried using a for loop as suggested on similar solutions I found here in SO but it didn't work. I guess I am not adding it where it should be in order to control the flow.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

```
const tracks = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"]
// 

const newAudioTracks = () => {
  tracks.forEach(function(track) {
    const button = document.querySelector(`#track-${track}`);
    const musicTrack = new Audio(`/music/track${track}.mp3`);
    musicTrack.id = track;
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      musicTrack.paused ? musicTrack.play() : musicTrack.pause();
    })
  })
}

newAudioTracks();
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you have too many musicTrack, which you will play on click. Definitely, when you click on another music track. It would not work. A possible approach would be have a single music track to play. And if the previous music track is not finish before the next run is  clicked, you may stop and remove it, then play the new music track.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your event will be fired for just one element, then you need to iterate over the others pausing one by one.

Here is one example, I passed the attribute controls instead of creating an external button to play, but the logic is the same if you use a custom button.

```js
const tracks = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('audio'));

tracks.forEach(function(track) {
    track.addEventListener('play', (event) => {
      tracks.forEach(function(track) {
        if(track !== event.target) track.pause();
      })
    })
})
```

```html
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Test_mp3_opus_16kbps.wav" controls></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Test_mp3_opus_16kbps.wav" controls></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Test_mp3_opus_16kbps.wav" controls></audio>
<audio src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8f/Test_mp3_opus_16kbps.wav" controls></audio>
```